# Unable to find field when running test on Device Farm

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

I’m trying to write a test using Java/TestNG running on AWS's Device Farm; however I cannot find my "account" field.

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage {

    @iOSFindBy(accessibility = "account")
    public IOSElement accountField;

    public HomePage(AppiumDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
    driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@Test
public void selectAccount() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    HomePage page = new HomePage(driver);
    new TouchAction(driver).tap(page.accountField).perform();
}
```

Running this test on device farm gives me this error:

```
selectAccount failed: Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map: - native content: "By.AccessibilityId: account" - html content: "by id or name "account""
```

**Relevant Local Logs**

```
...

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"webStorageEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"browserName":"","platform":"MAC","javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"app":"/Users/..../Downloads/.....ipa","platformVersion":"11.3.1","automationName":"XCUITest","platformName":"iOS","udid":".....","deviceName":"iPhone SE"}
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /elements] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/1470E279-8FD3-4CFE-944C-051CDF7F2A25/elements] with body: {"using":"accessibility id","value":"account"}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":[{"ELEMENT":"0C000000-0000-0000-1701-000000000000"}],"sessionId":"1470E279-8FD3-4CFE-944C-051CDF7F2A25","status":0}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: [{"ELEMENT":"0C000000-0000-0000-1701-000000000000"}]

...
```

**Relevant Device Farm Logs**

```
...

New IosDriver session created successfully, session 1dd93c26-55f6-4fdd-9963-2e3dbbc17386 added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1528814874003 (14:47:54 GMT+0000 (UTC))
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {\"webStorageEnabled\":false,\"locationContextEnabled\":false,\"browserName\":\"iPhone\",\"platform\":\"MAC\",\"javascriptEnabled\":true,\"databaseEnabled\":false,\"takesScreenshot\":true,\"networkConnectionEnabled\":false,\"platformName\":\"iOS\",\"version\":\"\",\"platformVersion\":\"9.3\",\"deviceName\":\".....\",\"app\":\"/tmp/scratch4iVs4j.scratch/share-CjbXpc.scratch/app-3ZPujz.ipa\",\"udid\":\".....\",\"desired\":{\"browserName\":\"iPhone\",\"platformName\":\"iOS\",\"version\":\"\",\"platform\":\"MAC\",\"platformVersion\":\"9.3\",\"deviceName\":\".....\",\"app\":\"/tmp/scratch4iVs4j.scratch/share-CjbXpc.scratch/app-3ZPujz.ipa\",\"udid\":\".....\"}}

...

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getCurrentContext() result: \"NATIVE_APP\"
<-- GET /wd/hub/session/1dd93c26-55f6-4fdd-9963-2e3dbbc17386/context 200 18 ms - 84
--> POST /wd/hub/session/1dd93c26-55f6-4fdd-9963-2e3dbbc17386/elements {\"using\":\"accessibility id\",\"value\":\"account\"}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: [\"accessibility id\",\"account\",\"1dd93c26-55f6-4fdd-9963-2e3dbbc17386\"]
[iOS] Executing iOS command 'findElements'
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, -ios uiautomation, accessibility id
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[UIAuto] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementsByAccessibilityId('account')
[UIAuto] Socket data received (25 bytes)
[UIAuto] Got result from instruments: {\"status\":0,\"value\":[]}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
<-- POST /wd/hub/session/1dd93c26-55f6-4fdd-9963-2e3dbbc17386/elements 200 834 ms - 74

...
```

I have made a screen shot after the 35 second implicit wait and confirmed my field is on the page.

I have also tried this method for selecting the account field without success:

```
@Test
public void selectAccount() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.name("account"));
    new TouchAction(driver).tap(el).perform();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to find my "account" field? This works locally using appium.

Comment: Could you please add the appium server logs from the device farm test and your local execution?

Comment: Sure! Let me know if you need more info from them. I've tried messing around with the device capabilities with no luck. I've tried a couple other techniques for waiting on the element to get on the page also: I added `@WithTimeout(time = 5000, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` below the `@iOSFindBy` annotation and added this wait command `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(page.account));`after `HomePage page = new HomePage(driver);` with no luck. All still passes locally, just not on device farm

Comment: It looks like Device farm is  using uiautomation and I bet your local logs are using xcui. Could you confirm that when you have the chance?

Comment: If that is the case try using an iOS device with OS level of 10 or greater and see if it works then.  Device farm should choose xcui as the automation name then if it's not set in code and it might make a difference.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. I can confirm that the local test run is using xcui. It seems that IOS 11 works on device farm but IOS 10 and less does not work even after setting the automationName device capability to XCUITest. Going off of https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest.md, that's the only capability that I would need to manually set since device farm takes care of the platformName, platformVersion, deviceName, and app capabilities right? Am I missing something to make < iOS11 devices work? It Also it seems like `plus` phones do not work IOS 11

Comment: Try again but don't set the automation name. Device Farm will choose it on our behalf and trying to use that capability may conflict with what device farm does. From my experience it will use XCUI for iOS 10 and above and uiautomation for lower than 10. 

I think this difference is the cause of the issue. If you use uiautomation locally does the same issue happen?

Comment: any update on the local execution using uiautomation?

Comment: Hello again, I have decided to test the current devices working on Device Farm for now to get things moving again. Thank you for all the help. I will circle back around to this in the future to see if I can get through it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing an Android app in ADF, and was facing the same issue, but setting up the `automationName` desired capability works for me.

```
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
```